# The ratio of the largest to the smallest side.

Tags: geometry

> If each of the two sides of a triangle is not smaller than the side to which it is drawn, then the ratio of the greatest and the smallest sides of the triangle is:

I am going to say, for a triangle $\triangle ABC$ that a > b > c and thus $A > B > C$ where the capital letter is the angle (opposite to the side).

Thus:

It seems that the angles (respectively) are $90, 60, 30$ each in degrees. And so with the law of sines, this shows:

$a/c = 2$.But this isn't right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Does an arbitrarily thin scalene triangle satisfy your constraints?

Comment: @Element118, no clue, I didnt make this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key words in the question are "**each** .... sides **not smaller**..."

This can happen only for an equilateral triangle, and ratio is 1:1

Comment: This is a bad question, i think. The answer is Sqrt(2) though for some reason.

Comment: I think this answer would be correct if the question stated, "any two sides of a triangle are not smaller than the side to which each is drawn..." but as stated, we have no way to interpret what "each of the two sides of a triangle" means.

Comment: I agree that it is a bad question. $\sqrt2$ seems to be the ratio when a right angled triangle is an isosceles triangle, but this is the **minimum** ratio in the limit.